# Java Script Cookie expire date

Tags: javascript, cookies

how do I get the cookie to expire in 6 month with this code:

```
<script>
var optOutLink = document.getElementById("opt-out-button");
  
if(optOutLink) {
    optOutLink.onclick = function() {
        document.cookie = 'opt-out=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Everytime I try a solution the code stops working.

thanks

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to _show us_ what you actually tried - then we can help you figure out, where you went wrong.

Comment: you change the expiration date: `Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC`

Comment: My latest try was this:
<script>
var optOutLink = document.getElementById("opt-out-button");
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));


if(optOutLink) {
    optOutLink.onclick = function() {
        document.cookie = 'opt-out=true; expires='+d.toUTCString()+';'; path=/';
        return false;
    }
}
</script>